# Laravel 5.3 mail settings being ignored

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

I have amended the .env file with the correct setting for my mail server:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=***********.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=*************
MAIL_PASSWORD=*************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

but when I try it out via the forgot password I always get:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269: 
Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection refused #111]
```

I have searched to find out another instance of mailtrap.io but can only find it in the example of env.

Comment: Did you happen to run php artisan config:cache at anytime? That will ignore any of your dynamic config variables. I would also check your config/mail.php file and make sure it is using the proper ENV variables

Comment: I am using shared hosting and do not have SSH access, but I looked in the cache directory and it was blank. I also have checked mail.php.

Comment: Try dd() some of the mail config variables to see if they are being read at all. Won't fix the problem, but at least you might be able to pinpoint where it is happening

Comment: sorry to be a bit thick but eactly where and how to include the dd()?

Comment: Somewhere in your controller before the mail send, try adding dd(config('mail.host')). Make sure that matches what you have in your .env file. If not, the .env value Is not being read

Comment: This happen because you dont have access to that port in that host. Unless you open the port in the server, you will not be able to send any email from your app. Since you are using a shared hosting you will not be able to do that by yourself, so try to contact the support service and see if the can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. It seems that it was a fault in my ftp client (Fileziller). It was reporting that it had uploaded the file OK but indeed it had not. When I went on the server and looked at the datetime of the record is was wrong.

I erased it and reuploaded and all was well.

A lesson for the future!